# adding numbers in textfield with add button java

Tags: java, button, applet, awt, actionlistener

I am trying to write a `textfield` and a button using applet. The main problem is that I cannot seem to figure out how to add multiple numbers such as one number then hit the add button then the number then add button and display the total as well in the same textfield like the basic calculator program. Here is what I've got so far:

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Button;
import java.awt.TextField;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;


public class addition extends Applet implements ActionListener {
    TextField tf;
    Button btnAdd;
    Button btnEqual;
    Button btnExit;

    public addition() {
        tf = new TextField(15);
        btnAdd = new Button(" + ");
        btnEqual = new Button(" = ");
        btnExit = new Button("exit");
    }

    public void init() {
        add(tf);
        add(btnAdd);
        add(btnEqual);
        add(btnExit);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == btnAdd.getFocusListeners()) {
            tf.setText("text goes here");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please clarify what you need help with?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
tf.repaint();
```

to tell the Component to layout again with the new value.

This is a classic failure in programming. This is only automatic with a valid data binding e.g. when a table is setup with data binding.

**EDIT:**
Your code looks fine so far, the source of the action is the button itself not a FocusListener :

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (e.getSource() == btnAdd) {
        tf.setText("text goes here");
        // create sum here (class variable, should be 0 at start)
        // update TF with new value
        // tell TF or Panel underneath to layout newly  
    }
    if (e.getSource() == btnEqual){
        // update value
        // layout newly
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey THarms, i want to add integers or numbers in the textfield just like a calculator by putting a number in the textfield then press the add button then put another number in the textfield then press the add button again and so on and so forth. I was wondering if i write a for loop of a scanner variable input but i seemed to be stuck i cant figure out the logic, any help will be appreciated thanks

Comment: I will try that if i get stuck then i will you and others Thank You

Comment: or anyone i cant figure out how to add 1 multiple times by pressing these two buttons ( button 1 and add button) and the same thing with button two ) and also adding two buttons i came up with this so far but cant seems to figure out where i have to put the code to add multiple 1 or 2's or both. Can you help me please?
Another word, can we add multiple button press action listener to get result?

Comment: i came up with this so far:
' if (e.getSource() == one) tf.setText(String.valueOf(varOne)); if (e.getSource() == two) tf.setText(String.valueOf(varTwo)); '